# Swift - (String) unable to read data

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error – (String) unable to read data – when I click on some buttons from my ViewController.swift in my Swift MVC calculator (such as "/", "+", "-"), but not when I click on "*", even though the code seems the same. I set a breakpoint at the "=" symbol, and inspect my model's object data structure and private variables in my Model.swift. Upon inspection, it seems that I'm trying to read from a nil value, as if it's a memory-access bug... It just doesn't make sense. Did I miss something in my program logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not even be a programming problem, per-say. You may have simply forgotten to connect the correct buttons in your View, Main.storyboard by default, to your ViewController.swift in the proper IBAction method.

To see if this is the case, you can right-click on the button in your view, then see what method your button is hooked up to (if any). If it isn't hooked up to any methods, control-click on the button and drag it over to the correct method in your ViewController.swift. However, if it is connected to more methods than you intended (probably if it's connected to more than one method, that should be an indicator of a possible source of error), in that same drop-down menu, click on the "×"-symbol to remove that connection from your Main.storyboard.

If none of these solved your problem, make sure your Model.swift really does have sound logic, and make sure you ended up correctly interfacing between your Main.storyboard, your ViewController.swift, and your Model.swift.

I hope this is helpful to others with a similar problem, who were baffled by the same type of error message!

Some possibly helpful images:

A UIButton connected to one too many IBAction methods in the ViewController.swift:
[image: A UIButton connected to one too many IBAction methods in the ViewController.swift]

A UIButton not connected to any IBAction methods:
[image: A UIButton not connected to any IBAction methods]

An example of connecting a UIButton to an IBAction method:
[image: An example of connecting a UIButton to an IBAction method]